# K2PDFOPT and highlights in Kindle Paperwhite

Tags: kindle, highlighting

I converted a PDF file using K2PDFOPT to use it in my Kindle Paperwhite.

But now I can not highlight the text in this file while reading it in my Kindle.

Can you tell me why?

Gustavo

Answer (score 1):

An updated answer from the [k2pdfopt FAQ](http://willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/faq.shtml) is below (I just updated it--I highlighted the key part of it here).  If you can't get this feature to work, a sample of your source PDF would help.  See also the [k2pdfopt native output help page](http://willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/native.shtml) and [OCR help page](http://willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/ocr.shtml).

> **Is there any way to search / highlight the text in the converted PDF file?**
>
> Yes, as of v1.50, k2pdfopt has OCR capability, and as of v1.60,
>   k2pdfopt has options for native PDF output, much like Cut2Col, SoPDF,
>   and the latest version of PaperCrop. **In fact, as of v2.00, if the text
>   in your source PDF document can be searched or highlighted, the
>   default output from k2pdfopt should have the same functionality using
>   the new virtual OCR feature (see "major new features" under v2.00 in
>   the version history for more details).** Note that PDF highlighting is
>   not possible on some e-readers, such as early Kindles (Kindle 1/2).